# Can we have two .master pages for single application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new to .net

I am working on .master page which is having my application's HEADER,FOOTER and MENU. But I have 2 applications. one is 'A' other one is 'B'. I have sub application named 'A1' under application 'A'.

I need to access A1 under Application A with menu, header, footer. I need to access the same A1 through B by HREF link but WITHOUT HEADER, FOOTER, MENU.

Is this possible using the single .master page. or it needs 2 master pages to achieve this in C#.

Comment: what is the expected behaviour from B? Click the link and the page loads, BUT, with the master page/header/footer/etc of B instead of A?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible either way. You can have the header, footer and menu visible on some condition in a single master page. Or you can have two separate master pages. You can also have a master page that has a master page. The choice is yours.